# after centering background color of tag remove

Tags: html, css, margin

Just a simple confusion. After centering html tag, background color is removed. But if I set float, background color works.

**This doesn't work**

```
article{
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:red;
}
```

**This works**

```
article{
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: what if you specify a height to both ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif height doesn't work, I found solution, problem is in html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one work as it is.

html:

```
<article>Article text</article>
```

css:

```
article{
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:red;
}
```

You can see [here](https://codepen.io/radu_cruceana/pen/BmRpKV)

Answer (score -1):

Can I see the HTML code? Otherwise, if you are using Chrome open up the console and inspect the element to see the styles being applied. To open up the console, right-click anywhere on the browser window and click on inspect and on the top left corner of the console window you will see an icon to select elements on the page to inspect.

Comment: Yeah, I found solution, the problem is in html code. Thanks for your response